# java.lang.ClassCastException error when I make xml unmarshaling of a mock endpoint

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, soap, unmarshalling

I'm working on a project that use SOAP technology and I'm new on this technology. I have the following source files (I have write the source files to be sure that You have a full view of project)

Panel_Abstract.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    targetNamespace="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel"
    xmlns:tns="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel"
    xmlns:prepaiduserinfo="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/prepaid/userinfo"
    xmlns:panel="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer"
    name="ConsumerPanel"
    xmlns:wsr="http://www.openuri.org/2002/10/soap/reliability/"
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:soap12enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
    xmlns:conv="http://www.openuri.org/2002/04/wsdl/conversation/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:import namespace="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel" schemaLocation="./Panel.xsd"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer" schemaLocation="./ConsumerCommonEntities.xsd"/>
            <xs:import namespace="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/prepaid/userinfo" schemaLocation="./PanelEntitiesPrepaidUserInfo.xsd" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="getPrepaidUserInfo">
        <wsdl:part name="prepaidUserInfoRequest" element="tns:getPrepaidUserInfo" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="getPrepaidUserInfoResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="result" element="tns:getPrepaidUserInfoResponse" />
    </wsdl:message>
    
    <wsdl:portType name="WEBPanelServicesPort">
            <wsdl:operation name="getPrepaidUserInfo">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:getPrepaidUserInfo" />
            <wsdl:output message="tns:getPrepaidUserInfoResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Panel_Concrete.wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:tns="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel"
    targetNamespace=http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel"
    xmlns:wsr="http://www.openuri.org/2002/10/soap/reliability/"
    xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/"
    xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:soap12enc="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
    xmlns:conv="http://www.openuri.org/2002/04/wsdl/conversation/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="ConsumerPanel">

    <wsdl:import namespace="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel" location="./Panel_Abstract.wsdl"/>

    <wsdl:binding name="WEBPanelServicesPort" type="tns:WEBPanelServicesPort">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
            <wsdl:operation name="getPrepaidUserInfo">
                <soap:operation soapAction="getPrepaidUserInfo" style="document" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="WEBPanelServices">
        <wsdl:port name="WEBPanelServicesPort" binding="tns:WEBPanelServicesPort">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:7001/PanelWebService/WEBPanelServices" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Panel.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:ns="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel"
    xmlns:panel="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer"
    xmlns:prepaidUserInfoPanel="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/prepaid/userinfo"
    targetNamespace="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
    
    <xs:import namespace="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/prepaid/userinfo" schemaLocation="./PanelEntitiesPrepaidUserInfo.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer" schemaLocation="./ConsumerCommonEntities.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="getPrepaidUserInfo" type="prepaidUserInfoPanel:PrepaidUserInfoRequest" nillable="true"/>
    <xs:element name="getPrepaidUserInfoResponse" type="prepaidUserInfoPanel:PrepaidUserInfoResponse" nillable="true"/>
</xs:schema>
```

PanelEntitiesPrepaidUserInfo.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:prepaiduserinfo="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/prepaid/userinfo" 
    xmlns:commonPanel="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/prepaid/userinfo">
    <xs:import namespace="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer" schemaLocation="./ConsumerCommonEntities.xsd"/>

    <xs:complexType name="PrepaidUserInfoRequest">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="commonPanel:UserInfoRequest">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="month" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="PrepaidUserInfoResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="SIMExpirationDate" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="autoRechargeBonusAsSeconds" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="autoRechargeBonusAsSecondsExtended" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="autoRechargeFlag" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="autoRechargeGapToBonusAsSeconds" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="autoRechargeRolloverCount" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="autoRechargeRolloverMax" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="bonusAsBytes" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="bonusAsEuros" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="credit" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="creditCompany" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="languageID" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="lastCreditSynchDate" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="lastEventDescription" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="profileID" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="profileName" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:int" name="profileType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="commonPanel:ResponseHeader" name="responseHeader" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="secondsWonByPromotion" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="smsWonByPromotion" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="trafficAmountEndDate" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="trafficAmountStartDate" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="xtensionContractID" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="xtensionProfileName" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="prepaiduserinfo:PrepaidXtensionTrafficContainer" name="xtensionTraffic" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="PrepaidXtensionTrafficContainer">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="dataBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="dataTotalBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="mmsSentReceivedBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="mmsSentReceivedEvent" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="payformeBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="payformeDuration" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="smsMmsTotalBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="smsMmsTotalEvent" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="smsSentReceivedBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="smsSentReceivedEvent" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="totalBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="vasBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="voiceIntercommBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="voiceIntercommDuration" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="voiceInternationalBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="voiceInternationalDuration" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="voiceNationalBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="voiceNationalDuration" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="voiceRoamingBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="voiceRoamingDuration" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="voiceTotalBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="voiceTotalDuration" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="wapBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="wifiBalance" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

ConsumerCommonEntities.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:commonPanel="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer"
               targetNamespace="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer"
               elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
        <xs:complexType name="RequestHeader">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="msisdn" type="xs:string" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="system" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element name="transactionID" type="xs:string" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="ResponseHeader">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="msisdn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" default="-1" />
            <xs:element name="responseCode" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
            <xs:element name="transactionID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" default="-1" />
        </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="BasicUserInfoRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="msisdn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" default="-1" />
            <xs:element name="system" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" default="-1" />
            <xs:element name="transactionID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" default="-1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="UserInfoRequest">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="commonPanel:BasicUserInfoRequest">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="sendNotification" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" default="-1" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
```

PrepaidUserInfoResponse.java

```
//
// Questo file è stato generato dall'Eclipse Implementation of JAXB, v2.3.7 
// Vedere https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri 
// Qualsiasi modifica a questo file andrà persa durante la ricompilazione dello schema di origine. 
// Generato il: 2023.07.06 alle 03:41:54 PM CEST 
//


package xxx.address.tmp.model.consumer.prepaid;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlProperty;

import xxx.address.tmp.model.consumer.ResponseHeader;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PrepaidUserInfoResponse", namespace = "http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/prepaid/userinfo", propOrder = {
    "simExpirationDate",
    "autoRechargeBonusAsSeconds",
    "autoRechargeBonusAsSecondsExtended",
    "autoRechargeFlag",
    "autoRechargeGapToBonusAsSeconds",
    "autoRechargeRolloverCount",
    "autoRechargeRolloverMax",
    "bonusAsBytes",
    "bonusAsEuros",
    "credit",
    "creditCompany",
    "languageID",
    "lastCreditSynchDate",
    "lastEventDescription",
    "profileID",
    "profileName",
    "profileType",
    "responseHeader",
    "secondsWonByPromotion",
    "smsWonByPromotion",
    "trafficAmountEndDate",
    "trafficAmountStartDate",
    "xtensionContractID",
    "xtensionProfileName",
    "xtensionTraffic"
})
public class PrepaidUserInfoResponse {
    
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "SIMExpirationDate")
    @XmlElement(name = "SIMExpirationDate", required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String simExpirationDate;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String autoRechargeBonusAsSeconds;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String autoRechargeBonusAsSecondsExtended;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String autoRechargeFlag;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String autoRechargeGapToBonusAsSeconds;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String autoRechargeRolloverCount;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String autoRechargeRolloverMax;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String bonusAsBytes;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String bonusAsEuros;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String credit;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String creditCompany;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String languageID;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String lastCreditSynchDate;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String lastEventDescription;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String profileID;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String profileName;
    @XmlElement(defaultValue = "-1")
    protected int profileType;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected ResponseHeader responseHeader;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String secondsWonByPromotion;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String smsWonByPromotion;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String trafficAmountEndDate;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String trafficAmountStartDate;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String xtensionContractID;
    @XmlElement(required = true, defaultValue = "-1", nillable = true)
    protected String xtensionProfileName;
    @XmlElement(required = true, nillable = true)
    protected PrepaidXtensionTrafficContainer xtensionTraffic;

    public String getSIMExpirationDate() {
        return simExpirationDate;
    }

    public void setSIMExpirationDate(String value) {
        this.simExpirationDate = value;
    }

    //all the rest is all of get and set method

}
```

ObjectFactory.java

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _GetPrepaidUserInfo_QNAME = new QName(http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel", "getPrepaidUserInfo");
    private final static QName _GetPrepaidUserInfoResponse_QNAME = new QName("http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel", "PrepaidUserInfoResponse");
    
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link PrepaidUserInfoRequest }{@code >}
     * 
     * @param value
     *     Java instance representing xml element's value.
     * @return
     *     the new instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link PrepaidUserInfoRequest }{@code >}
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel", name = "getPrepaidUserInfo")
    public JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoRequest> createGetPrepaidUserInfo(PrepaidUserInfoRequest value) {
        return new JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoRequest>(_GetPrepaidUserInfo_QNAME, PrepaidUserInfoRequest.class, null, value);
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link PrepaidUserInfoResponse }{@code >}
     * 
     * @param value
     *     Java instance representing xml element's value.
     * @return
     *     the new instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}{@link PrepaidUserInfoResponse }{@code >}
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel", name = "PrepaidUserInfoResponse")
    public JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse> createGetPrepaidUserInfoResponse(PrepaidUserInfoResponse value) {
        return new JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse>(_GetPrepaidUserInfoResponse_QNAME, PrepaidUserInfoResponse.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

PrepaidUserInfoMock.xml

```
<PrepaidUserInfoResponse xmlns="http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel">
<SIMExpirationDate>20240707235959</SIMExpirationDate>
<autoRechargeBonusAsSeconds>-1</autoRechargeBonusAsSeconds>
<autoRechargeBonusAsSecondsExtended>0</autoRechargeBonusAsSecondsExtended> 
<autoRechargeFlag>0</autoRechargeFlag>
<autoRechargeGapToBonusAsSeconds>-1</autoRechargeGapToBonusAsSeconds>
<autoRechargeRolloverCount>-1</autoRechargeRolloverCount>
<autoRechargeRolloverMax>0x7ff0000000000000L</autoRechargeRolloverMax>
<bonusAsBytes>-1</bonusAsBytes>
<bonusAsEuros>0.00</bonusAsEuros>
<credit>3.02</credit>
<creditCompany>-1</creditCompany>
<languageID>1</languageID>
<lastCreditSynchDate>20230709020514</lastCreditSynchDate>
<lastEventDescription>Attivazione/rinnovo offerta</lastEventDescription>
<profileID>286</profileID>
<profileName>PIANO BLA BLA</profileName>
<profileType>0</profileType>
<responseHeader>
    <msisdn>3388237629</msisdn>
    <responseCode>200</responseCode>
    <transactionID>3333333333_1111111111146_608.0_239.0</transactionID>
</responseHeader>
<secondsWonByPromotion>-1</secondsWonByPromotion>
<smsWonByPromotion>-1</smsWonByPromotion>
<trafficAmountEndDate>-1</trafficAmountEndDate>
<trafficAmountStartDate>-1</trafficAmountStartDate>
<xtensionContractID>-1</xtensionContractID>
<xtensionProfileName>-1</xtensionProfileName>
<xtensionTraffic>
    <dataBalance>-1</dataBalance>
    <dataTotalBalance>-1</dataTotalBalance>
    <mmsSentReceivedBalance>-1</mmsSentReceivedBalance>
    <mmsSentReceivedEvent>-1</mmsSentReceivedEvent>
    <payformeBalance>-1</payformeBalance>
    <payformeDuration>-1</payformeDuration>
    <smsMmsTotalBalance>-1</smsMmsTotalBalance>
    <smsMmsTotalEvent>-1</smsMmsTotalEvent>
    <smsSentReceivedBalance>-1</smsSentReceivedBalance>
    <smsSentReceivedEvent>-1</smsSentReceivedEvent>
    <totalBalance>-1</totalBalance>
    <vasBalance>-1</vasBalance>
    <voiceIntercommBalance>-1</voiceIntercommBalance>
    <voiceIntercommDuration>-1</voiceIntercommDuration>
    <voiceInternationalBalance>-1</voiceInternationalBalance>
    <voiceInternationalDuration>-1</voiceInternationalDuration>
    <voiceNationalBalance>-1</voiceNationalBalance>
    <voiceNationalDuration>-1</voiceNationalDuration>
    <voiceRoamingBalance>-1</voiceRoamingBalance>
    <voiceRoamingDuration>-1</voiceRoamingDuration>
    <voiceTotalBalance>-1</voiceTotalBalance>
    <voiceTotalDuration>-1</voiceTotalDuration>
    <wapBalance>-1</wapBalance>
    <wifiBalance>-1</wifiBalance>
</xtensionTraffic>
</PrepaidUserInfoResponse>
```

WebServiceConfig.java

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig  extends WsConfigurerAdapter  {

    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebServiceConfig.class);
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        //return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/ws/*");
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/*");
    }

   
    @Bean(name = "Panel")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema panelSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("WEBPanelServicesPort");
        //wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel");
        wsdl11Definition.setServiceName("WEBPanelServices");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(panelSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public XsdSchema panelSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("wsdl/Panel.xsd"));
    }
}
```

GetPrepaidUserInfoEndPoint.java

```
@Endpoint
public class GetPrepaidUserInfoEndPoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getPrepaidUserInfo")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse> getPrepaidUserInfo(@RequestPayload PrepaidUserInfoRequest request){

        JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse> prepaidUserInfo = null;
        xxx.address.tmp.model.consumer.prepaid.ObjectFactory factory = new xxx.address.tmp.model.consumer.prepaid.ObjectFactory();
        ObjectFactory factoryPanel = new ObjectFactory();
        PrepaidUserInfoResponse response = factory.createPrepaidUserInfoResponse();
        
        URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fallback/PrepaidUserInfoMock.xml");

        File mock;
        try {
            mock = new File(resource.toURI());
        
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
            javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            response = (PrepaidUserInfoResponse) unmarshaller.unmarshal(mock);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.toString());
        }
        finally {
            prepaidUserInfo = factoryPanel.createGetPrepaidUserInfoResponse(response);
        }
        return prepaidUserInfo;
    }

}
```

I have cutted all the possible lines of code to reduce the size. When call the endpoint from soapui I'll get "java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast to xxx.address.tmp.model.consumer.prepaid.PrepaidUserInfoResponse" error. What is the cause ?

After that, can You check if the 2 wsdl, Panel.xsd and WebServiceConfig.java are conceptual correct? (for example in WebServiceConfig.java class, the XsdSchema panelSchema parameter name in defaultWsdl11Definition should match with @Bean
public XsdSchema panelSchema() method more under, but if name doesn't match compiler however give "Build success")

Comment: You get a `JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse>` instead of a `PrepaidUserInfoResponse` from the marshaller. Which makes sense as that is what you are wrapping it to any way. So just do `return unmarshaller.unmarshal(mock);` and fix the casting to `(JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse>)`. Then you can remove the ObjectFactory and call to it. No need for that. I'm not going to validate your WSDLs for you.

Comment: if I write "prepaidUserInfo = unmarshaller.unmarshal(mock);" instead of "response = (PrepaidUserInfoResponse) unmarshaller.unmarshal(mock);" compiler give me error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse>"

Comment: If you would've read the second sentence of my comment -> *fix the casting to `(JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse>)`*.

Comment: What should I write?

Comment: You have write also "Then you can remove the ObjectFactory and call to it." . What does it mean?

Comment: you just need to do `return (JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse>) unmarshaller.unmarshall(mock);` you don't need to code after that hence no need for the `new ObjectFactory()` either.

Comment: ok, before Your answer I have write "prepaidUserInfo = (JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(mock);" and comment the line inside finally block "prepaidUserInfo = factoryPanel.createGetPrepaidUserInfoResponse(response);" but answer is empty

Comment: Then your unmarshalling doesn't work (or it doesn't read the file). A `File` has to be an actual resource you are loading from the classpath so that will probably fail. Instead use `new ClassPathResource("fallback/PrepaidUserInfoMock.xml")` and get an `InputStream` from it and pass that to the `unmarshall` method instead of a `File`.

Comment: objectfactory class, for reason that I don't know because I work inside a team, it's splitted in 2 class objectfactory class, so in the class used inside jaxbcontext there isn't /**
     * Create an instance of {@link PrepaidUserInfoResponse }
     * 
     */
    public PrepaidUserInfoResponse createPrepaidUserInfoResponse() {
        return new PrepaidUserInfoResponse();
    } ... Can be this the cause?

Comment: You don't need the `ObjectFactory`. And no it isn't the cause. You are trying to much and I suspect that you have no clue on how the technologies you use are actually working.

Comment: with "prepaidUserInfo = (JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ClassPathResource("fallback/PrepaidUserInfoMock.xml").getInputStream());" still doesn't work

Comment: As I mention in my answer your exception handling is flawed as well as it continues as is without failing. Make that proper and you probably get an exception exactly telling you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have solved the problem: when are created the JAXB classes with Eclipse tool, it's created also a class named package-info.java that has the folowing content:

package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package xxx.address.tmp.model.consumer.prepaid;
```

so, can occur the following issues:

1. if namespace value in @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema in package-info.java ("http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer") it's different from xmlns attribute of root element on xml file mock (in my case xmlns value attribute is "http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel" while root element is "PrepaidUserInfoResponse" you'll get a javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel", local:"PrepaidUserInfoResponse"). Expected element are <{http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer}PrepaidUserInfoResponse> .
2. if namespace value in @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema and xmlns attribute of root element on xml file mock are the same (in my case "http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer") but are different from attribute namespace in @XmlType annotation in PrepaidUserInfoResponse.java (in my case "http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/prepaid/userinfo") You'll get a response with empty values.

I have also obtained a "java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast to xxx.address.tmp.model.consumer.prepaid.PrepaidUserInfoResponse" but I don't remember on what circustances.

Answer (score -1):

```java
@Endpoint
public class GetPrepaidUserInfoEndPoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://address.xxx/tmp/model/consumer/panel";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getPrepaidUserInfo")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse> getPrepaidUserInfo(@RequestPayload PrepaidUserInfoRequest request){
        var resource = new ClassPathResource("fallback/PrepaidUserInfoMock.xml");
        try {
       
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(PrepaidUserInfoResponse.class);
            javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            return (JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(resource.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Error creating response!". ex);
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error creating Response", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

You are trying to much here and seems to point to a lack of understand of what you are actually doing.

The `File` needs to be a physical resource on the file system. If you are running this as jar/war this won't work as it isn't a physical resource but packed inside a jar. Instead use a `ClasspathResource` from Spring to load it and use `getInputStream` to have it read.

Also fix the exception handling as when there is an error the process will continue and return an empty or no response.

You don't need all those `ObjectFactory` instances they don't really add anything. You can just call `unmarshall` and return the element you get from there.

Comment: what do You mean for "Also fix the exception handling as when there is an error the process will continue and return an empty or no response." ? In eclipse console (I have compiled with maven and execute with "Debug as") isn't showed any error

Comment: Because you are swallowing it and not throwing an exception, you should also log (or at least rethrow) the exception. Not just the message that way you loose context. Compare my code to your code...

Comment: I have write "prepaidUserInfo = (JAXBElement<PrepaidUserInfoResponse>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new ClassPathResource("fallback/PrepaidUserInfoMock.xml").getInputStream());" with "var resource" I'll get an error on ide .I have also written your code in exception block and no error are showed in the console on run-time

Comment: var type is unknow

Comment: `var` is a keyword available on Java17 and up (which I assumed you were on. Apparently you aren't, replace `var` with the actual type.